# Error with SQL and Python - table or view does not exist

Tags: python, sql, database, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am unable to run the scrip if I add `left JOIN t2 ON Col10 = Col1` as a command in the sql query in Python. Without it I can run the script with no problem.

the error I get is: SQL Error: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

PS- The script full script is working fine in SQL developer.

Any advise why?

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('......')

cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT \
    Col1, \
    Col2 \
    FROM t1 \
    left JOIN t2 ON Col10 = Col1"

cur.execute(sql)

sql_data = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
col_names = [row[0] for row in cur.description]
sql_data.columns = col_names
sql_data
```

Comment: You are not selecting Col10.

Comment: can it be table t2 is in different schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PS- The full script is working fine in SQL developer.

If that's the case, it means that user - you're connected to in SQL Developer - has access to both `t1` and `t2` tables.

---

If Oracle complains that

> ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

when you run the same `SELECT` statement from Python, it means that user you're connected to now

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('......')
```

doesn't have the privilege to access the `t2` table. That might be because

- you misspelled its name
- someone dropped the table so it doesn't exist any more in that schema
- it is owned by someone else but you're accessing it as the owner granted you privileges to do so (and those privileges have now been revoked)
- you use it as a public synonym which has been dropped

or some other reason. It is difficult to debug "generic" code you posted as, obviously, tables aren't really `t1` nor `t2` and columns aren't `col1` nor `col2` etc. Therefore, re-read what I've just said and try to find the culprit. Good luck!